# Saving a specific input of Maple code to LaTeX

Tags: maple2e

here is what I'm trying to do: test True/False for if there is an isomorphism in a group. If it is true, then I want Maple to save the inserted polynomial to a TeX file labeled "True.tex" or else to a file named "False.tex".

What I've tried:

`restart; with(algcurves); with(GroupTheory); Elements(GaloisGroup((1 - x)*(2*y^3 - 3) + x*(5*y^3 + 7*y^2 + 11*y + 13), y)); GroupOrder(GaloisGroup((1 - x)*(2*y^3 - 3) + x*(5*y^3 + 7*y^2 + 11*y + 13), y)); AreIsomorphic(GaloisGroup((1 - x)*(2*y^3 - 3) + x*(5*y^3 + 7*y^2 + 11*y + 13), y), Symm(3));`

Output: `{(12), (132), (123), (), (13), (23)}

```
                           6

                          true`
```

I now want to append "(1 - x)*(2*y^3 - 3) + x*(5*y^3 + 7*y^2 + 11*y + 13)" to my "True.tex" file automatically.

When I tried `writeto("True.tex"); LaTeX((1 - x)*(2*y^3 - 3) + x*(5*y^3 + 7*y^2 + 11*y + 13));`, I got

````
> Typesetting:-Parse(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mi("appendto", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mi(""), Typesetting:-ms("True.tex"), Typesetting:-mi("")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(";", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "true", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.2777778em"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mi("LaTeX", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mi("Elements", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mi("GaloisGroup", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("1", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&minus;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mi("x", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("2", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-msup(Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("3", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'superscriptshift' = "0"), Typesetting:-mo("&minus;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("3", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mi("x", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("5", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-msup(Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("3", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'superscriptshift' = "0"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("7", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-msup(Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("2", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'superscriptshift' = "0"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("11", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("13", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(",", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "true", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.3333333em"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic")), 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(";", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "true", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.2777778em"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mi("GroupOrder", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mi("GaloisGroup", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("1", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&minus;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mi("x", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("2", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-msup(Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("3", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'superscriptshift' = "0"), Typesetting:-mo("&minus;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("3", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mi("x", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("5", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-msup(Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("3", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'superscriptshift' = "0"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("7", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-msup(Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("2", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'superscriptshift' = "0"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("11", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("13", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(",", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "true", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.3333333em"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic")), 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(";", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "true", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.2777778em"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mi("AreIsomorphic", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mi("GaloisGroup", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("1", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&minus;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mi("x", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("2", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-msup(Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("3", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'superscriptshift' = "0"), Typesetting:-mo("&minus;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("3", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mi("x", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("5", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-msup(Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("3", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'superscriptshift' = "0"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("7", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-msup(Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("2", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'superscriptshift' = "0"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("11", 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo("&sdot;", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mo("+", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.2222222em", 'rspace' = "0.2222222em"), Typesetting:-mn("13", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(",", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "true", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.3333333em"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mi("y", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(",", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "true", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.3333333em"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em"), Typesetting:-mi("Symm", 'italic' = "true", 'mathvariant' = "italic"), Typesetting:-mfenced(Typesetting:-mrow(Typesetting:-mn("3", 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'mathvariant' = "normal")), 'mathvariant' = "normal"), Typesetting:-mo(" ", 'mathvariant' = "normal", 'fence' = "false", 'separator' = "false", 'stretchy' = "false", 'symmetric' = "false", 'largeop' = "false", 'movablelimits' = "false", 'accent' = "false", 'lspace' = "0.0em", 'rspace' = "0.0em")), 'mathvariant' = "normal")),return_statseq=true,evaluate=true);
                       /                                                      
Typesetting:-mambiguous\appendtoApplyFunction("True.tex")semi LaTeXApplyFunct\

                            //                     /                        / 
  ionTypesetting:-mambiguous\\ElementsApplyFunction\GaloisGroupApplyFunction\(

            /       3    \        /      3          2               \       \\
  1 - x)sdot\2 sdoty  - 3/ + xsdot\5sdoty  + 7 sdoty  + 11sdoty + 13/comma y//

                              /                        /           /       3
  semi GroupOrderApplyFunction\GaloisGroupApplyFunction\(1 - x)sdot\2 sdoty 

      \        /      3          2               \       \\                  
   - 3/ + xsdot\5sdoty  + 7 sdoty  + 11sdoty + 13/comma y//semi AreIsomorphic

               /                        /           /       3    \        / 
  ApplyFunction\GaloisGroupApplyFunction\(1 - x)sdot\2 sdoty  - 3/ + xsdot\5

       3          2               \       \                          \ \  
  sdoty  + 7 sdoty  + 11sdoty + 13/comma y/comma SymmApplyFunction(3)/ /, 

                                                   \\
  Typesetting:-merror("invalid function arguments")//
``` and a lot more.  How can I just have "(1 - x)*(2*y^3 - 3) + x*(5*y^3 + 7*y^2 + 11*y + 13)"?

Thanks in advance!
````

Comment: What version of Maple are you using?

Comment: @IanThompson, I'm using Maple 2021

Comment: I think I might know what the problem is, but I need to see your worksheet to be certain. Can you make it available for download from somewhere? If not, just follow the links from my user profile to find my work email address, and send it to me there.